# How to match Z coordinate for vertices from two different objects that share same X and Y coordinates?

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes, vertices

I wonder if anyone know a tip to  match Z coordinate for vertices from two different objects that share same X and Y coordinates ?
I work with very complex objects (a landcape and a road) and i need to
sew them together. The road is just a part of the landscape that I intersect with a volume, so I could sculpt to smooth its surafce. While sculptind, I locked the X and Y axis so the points are surimposed on the Z axis between the two objects. The idea now is to vertically match the landscape vertices with the one of the road.

[image: Landscape (selected) and road]
I'm not familiar with the geometry nodes or python scripts, but i guess i could use one of those to do this job ...
I have thousands of point to translate on Z axis so if anyone know a way to keep me from doing it one by one I would be very grateful :)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Just use the node `Raycast` with a *Ray Direction* of $(0,0-1)$ (from the terrain down to the street). Alternatively, it should also work with `Geometry Proximity`, but that basically depends on your mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Select a vertex that has the "target" Z value, press Shift S > cursor to selected.

Switch the pivot point to "3D cursor", select all vertices you want to move and press S, Z, 0, Enter.

When scaling you can enable proportional editing, so to smoothen out the junction.

[image]

If the terrain isn't flat you can use a shrinkwrap modifier, limited to a vertex group containing the vertices you want to move, using the "Project" mode (positive and negative) limited to Z axis.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but the road isn't flat (not obvious with the screenshot I uploaded, sorry) so their isn't one target Z value but each vertice has different Z value

Comment: I updated my answer.